# How to draw basic blocks in latex?

Tags: latex

I'm now learning something about compiler, Basic block is one important concept in it. So I want to do some notes, I wonder is there any useful package for drawing basic blocks?

maybe something like this :
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "drawing basic blocks"? Do you want to draw a rectangle?

Comment: I have update this question.

Comment: have a look at tikz

Answer (score 0):

As *samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz* pointed already out, have a look at the tikz-package (`\usepackage{tikz}`)

Here is a minimal working example of the first rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\draw (1, 0) rectangle  ++(2,1.5) node[pos=.5, text width=1.8cm, align=center] {\(x_{1} = y+z\) \\ \( x_{2}=x+2\) \\ \( x_{2} <2\)};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
`\( ... \)` is used for the inline math mode to display the mathematical expression as part of the paragraph.

Feel free to get inspired by the *tikz examples* at https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ . They tend to be very helpful at the beginning.